# run async while loop independently

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to run an async while loop independently of another one?

Instead of the actual code I isolated the issue I am having in the following example code

```
import asyncio, time

class Time:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_time = 0

    async def dates(self):
        while True:
            t = time.time()
            if self.start_time == 0:
                self.start_time = t
            yield t
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    async def printer(self):
        while True:

            print('looping') # always called

            await asyncio.sleep(self.interval)

    async def init(self):
        async for i in self.dates():
            if i == self.start_time: 
                self.interval = 3 
                await self.printer()
            print(i) # Never Called

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
t = Time()
loop.run_until_complete(t.init())
```

Is there a way to have the print function run independently so `print(i)` gets called each time?

What it should do is `print(i)` each second and every 3 seconds call `self.printer(i)`

Essentially self.printer is a separate task that does not need to be called very often, only every `x` seconds(in this case 3).

In JavaScript the solution is to do something like so
`setInterval(printer, 3000);`

EDIT: Ideally self.printer would also be able to be canceled / stopped if a condition or stopping function is called

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `asyncio` equivalent of JavaScript's `setTimeout` would be `asyncio.ensure_future`:

```
import asyncio

async def looper():
    for i in range(1_000_000_000):
        print(f'Printing {i}')
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

async def main():
    print('Starting')
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(looper())

    print('Waiting for a few seconds')
    await asyncio.sleep(4)

    print('Cancelling')
    future.cancel()

    print('Waiting again for a few seconds')
    await asyncio.sleep(2)

    print('Done')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: **Improvement**:  You can replace `for i in range(1_000_000_000):` with `while True:`....

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to register your `self.printer()` coroutine as a separate task; pass it to [`asyncio.ensure_future()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.ensure_future) rather than await on it directly:

```
asyncio.ensure_future(self.printer())
```

By passing the coroutine to `asyncio.ensure_future()`, you put it on the list of events that the loop switches between as each awaits on further work to be completed.

With that change, your test code outputs:

```
1516819094.278697
looping
1516819095.283424
1516819096.283742
looping
1516819097.284152
# ... etc.
```

Tasks are the asyncio equivalent of threads in a multithreading scenario.

Comment: Did you mean `asyncio.ensure_future(self.printer())` like in Blender's answer? Thanks btw!

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.