# Control+C not working while using asyncio.sleep() in while loop

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I can't seem to understand why `CTL+C` is not working.

I think it's something I don't yet understand about the way async functions work and `asyncio.sleep()`

However, I have found [this bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue39622) which might be related as well as people using event loops with async functions in python. Also, there are questions like [run async while loop independently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48429306/run-async-while-loop-independently) but they don't really answer my question or provide insight.

```
async def set_maintain_countdown_message(countdown, message):
    try:
        countdown_message = await app.send_message(
            message.chat.id,
            await get_formated_countdown(countdown)
            )
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(4, 8))
        while countdown['state'] == 'active':
            await countdown_message.edit(
                await get_formated_countdown(countdown)
            )
            await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(4, 8))

    except FloodWait as e:
        await asyncio.sleep(e.x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement it using [custom signal handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#set-signal-handlers-for-sigint-and-sigterm).

Unfortunately asyncio by default doesn't work that way, and for a major reason: If you have multiple coroutines waiting at once, which one will it cancel?

Also, I will not go into how asyncio is implemented internally, which I answered on a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51116910/1658617), but the interpreter isn't actually sleeping at that line of code, so a `KeyboardInterrupt` won't be thrown there.

Creating a custom signal handler to handle `SIGINT` is probably what you're looking for.

Keep in mind - if you do not use `asyncio.run()` to run the code, you must make sure you shut down the coroutines (cancelling everything) gracefully using [`loop.shutdown_asyncgens()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.shutdown_asyncgens).

Comment: `which one will it cancel`, as a consumer of the library, I don't care. I just want the signal handling to work. So the library maintainers should implement it in a manner such that the signal bubbles up the synchronous code wrapping around the async code. If that means cancelling all of them, then so be it.

Comment: @wheeler so you're saying that if you have 5 coroutines of different libraries you want a single library to cancel all of them by mistake including unrelated coroutines and everything else?

Comment: What I want is for the program to make a best-effort attempt to cleanly and immediately quit. Whether or not it is a "mistake" for a library to cancel all tasks in order for the program to come to a halt is irrelevant--the only mistake being made here is a program not coming to a halt when Ctrl + C is pressed.

Comment: That's what **you** @wheeler wish, and for that **you** should make a handler :-)
Python throws KeyboardInterrupt in the current location. If it is in a function, people can catch it and revert it. It won't continue throwing, just as it won't throw it in 20 other coroutines. If someone catches it in a coroutine, then what? It's a behavior that is impossible to define or determine. That's where your wish goes into the picture, and as a programmer, that's your responsibility to program.

Comment: @wheeler if you want, you can easily create a handle that `.cancel()`s all tasks, but be wary, as you will enter some places you probably wish you didn't, and plenty of bugs might pop up.